# How can I reference the first occurence of a given selector in CSS?

Tags: css

#### HTML:

```
<div class="foo">firstBar</div><!-- give this one a different style -->
<div class="foo">secondBar</div>
<div class="foo">thirdBar</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
 .foo { font-size: 12pt }
```

Without editing the existing HTML, is it possible to somehow reference the first occurence of the class "foo" and give it a different style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div:first-child { font-size: 12pt }
```

Note: For *:first-child* to work in IE a DOCTYPE must be declared. This won't work in IE6.

Comment: Also it's got to be the first child of the parent element, not just the first .foo of the parent. i.e. drop any element above the first div and the css won't do anything to the first foo.

Answer (score 0):

If the divs are contained in an outer div and the first foo was the first child of this outer div, you could use `div#outer_div + div.foo { font-size: 12pt }`

**EDIT:** Commenter is right, this wouldn't work. The way to do it with + would be to reset the font-size attribute for all the other div.foo's, ad infinitum:

div.foo + div.foo { ... }
div.foo + div.foo + div.foo { ... }

This wouldn't be a good way to go about it, so disregard my answer.

Comment: Isn't "+" the adjacent sibling selector, meaning that line will match any div.foo that shares the same parent as div#outer_div?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements succeed each other, you can use this:

```
.foo { font-size: 2em }
.foo + .foo { font-size: inherit }
```